How i can transform my Apns token on an FCM with expo?
I try to catch a fcm token from my app react native . No problem for android but for ios i have an error saying

code: 'messaging/invalid-argument',
message: 'The registration token is not a valid FCM registration token'

IU followed the documentation, and do this in front end:
export const getFcmToken = async () => {
  const projectId =
    Constants?.expoConfig?.extra?.eas?.projectId ??
    Constants?.easConfig?.projectId;

  console.log("constatrn", Constants.expoConfig);

  try {
    const { status: existingStatus } =
      await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
    let finalStatus = existingStatus;

    if (existingStatus !== "granted") {
      const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
      finalStatus = status;
    }

    if (finalStatus !== "granted") {
      alert("Échec de l'obtention du jeton pour les notifications push!");
      return;
    }

    const token = (await Notifications.getDevicePushTokenAsync()).data;
    console.log("Jeton Expo Push:", token);
    return token;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Erreur lors de l'obtention du jeton Expo push:", error);
  }
};

Then i call it with firebase Admin in my back this way
const sendNotification = async (
  userID: string,

  title: string,
  body: string
) => {
  try {
    let tokenArray: string[] = [];
    const getTok = await getToken(userID);

    getTok?.map((item: any) => {
      tokenArray.push(item.token);
    });

    console.log("tokenArray", tokenArray);

    // Envoyez la notification
    await firebaseAdmin
      .messaging()
      .sendEachForMulticast({
        tokens: tokenArray, // ['token_1', 'token_2', ...]
        data: {
          owner: "test",
          user: "test",
          picture: "",
        },
        apns: {
          payload: {
            aps: {
              // Required for background/quit data-only messages on iOS
              // Note: iOS frequently will receive the message but decline to deliver it to your app.
              //           This is an Apple design choice to favor user battery life over data-only delivery
              //           reliability. It is not under app control, though you may see the behavior in device logs.
              "content-available": true,
              // Required for background/quit data-only messages on Android
              priority: "high",
            },
          },
        },
      })

      .then((response: any) => {
        console.log("Response sent message:", response.responses[0].error);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error sending message:", error);
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Erreur lors de l'envoi de la notification:", error);
  }
};

Do i forget something in the front end to catch the good token ?
I tried to use expo notification to catch the fcm token but it looks like i catch the apns token
